# lmfit exponentialmodel does not fit at all

Tags: python, lmfit

I am trying to fit a very simple data as:

```
81
9
2
27
4
0
15
1
0
11
1
1
37
0
0
27
5
1
58
3
0
78
0
0
67
0
3
```

using `lmfit` as shown below.

```
import itertools

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from lmfit.models import (ExpressionModel, GaussianModel, ExponentialModel)

with open('result.dat') as fin:
  data = np.genfromtxt(itertools.islice(fin, 0, None, 3),
                       delimiter=',',
                       dtype='int')
data = np.cumsum(data)
print(data)
x = (np.linspace(0, len(data), len(data)))
model = ExponentialModel()
params = model.guess(data, x=x)
result = model.fit(data, params, x=x)
plt.plot(x, data, '.')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit)
plt.show()
print(params)
```

and the plot I am getting is:
[image: Result]

I have no idea why the exponential fit is failing so miserably. Any idea please? 
NB: The slice is due to the fact that I am I am taking every 3rd row.

Comment: Please post the actual code you used and provide the printed output.  Just to be clear, the code you posted could not possibly have generated the plot you show.  Show what you did.  What you decide to include from your post is deliberate communication, and what you remove is deliberately withholding information.

Comment: @MNewville, the mistake was corrected, if you had run the code, mistake was obvious.

Comment: well, your code will not run for me because I do not have the file `result.dat`.  The plot was absolutely not made with the code with you have posted.   But, ExponentialModel is an exponential **Decay**, and your data is not decaying.... you probably want to write your exponential model and maybe include an offset...